# Changing the scalar curvature (k = 0,+1,-1) with coordinate transformations?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, metric-tensor

I would like to prove that I can (or can't) change curvature of space, k = 0,+1,-1, via general coordinate transformations, which in principle can mix space and time coordinates together.

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61403/ricci-scalars-for-space-and-spacetime-local-and-global-curvature

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear about what you mean by the term "space".

I'm assuming you take your spacetime, and pick out a specific three dimensional submanifold $\Sigma$, say by a function $f(x^{\mu})=$ const.  You now compute the intrinsic Ricci curvature scalar for that submanifold.  Now you make a coordinate transformation $x'^{\mu} = x'^{\mu}(x^{\nu})$.  The new spatial coordinates are allowed to depend on the old $x^0$s.  In the new coordinates, the new function specifying the same $\Sigma$ will be different to $f$, but we can still calculate the intrinsic curvature of $\Sigma$ in the new coordinates.

This intrinsic curvature is a geometric property of $\Sigma$ independent of the embedding.  The Ricci scalar of $\Sigma$, i.e. $^3R$ assigns a number to each point in $\Sigma$.  This number is the same regardless of the values of the coordinate system used on $\Sigma$.

If, however, by "space" you had meant the surface $x^0=$const given by the chosen coordinate system, then when we change coordinates, $x'^0=$const represents a completely different submanifold which may have different intrinsic curvature.

Answer (score 0):

By the term "space" I meant this: If 4D metric is given by

G_μν = diag[1,-a(t)^2/1-kr^2,-a^2(t)r^2,-a(t)^2r^2sin(Θ)^2],

in some coordinates (t,r,Θ,ϕ), then a 3D "subspace" is simply

G_ij = diag[-a(t)^2/1-kr^2,-a^2(t)r^2,-a(t)^2r^2sin(Θ)^2],

which seems like your other case, surface of t=const.

Comment: Hi Winnie. Welcome to Physics.SE. This site uses an unique TeX markup style called MathJax. This markup is very useful for understanding math equations and parameters. Please have a look [here for an intro](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) or our [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation) for more info. For example, `$\mu$` results $\mu$, `$\omega$` inserts $\omega$, etc. It's quite interesting. You can revise your post if you can ;-)